# BCNF conversion

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, normalization

I am trying to comprehend [BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCNF) databasing and I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Consider the following relation:

```
R (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

The following functional dependences hold:

```
A -> E, F
A -> G
A, B -> D
B -> C
E, F -> G
A -> D
```

How would I make it [BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCNF)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking informally, in homework problems, you get to BCNF by

- assuming you're in at least 1NF,
- removing partial key dependencies to get to 2NF (at least),
- removing transitive dependencies to get to 3NF (at least), and finally
- removing remaining functional dependencies in which the left-hand side isn't a candidate key to get to BCNF (at least).

An example of a partial key dependency is the pair

```
AB->D
A->D
```

Since A alone determines D, the functional dependency AB->D has a partial key dependency.

An example of a transitive dependency is the pair

```
A->EF
EF->G
```

There's no guarantee that you can normalize a given relation to, say, BCNF *and no higher*. (This seems to cause a lot of confusion among university students on SO.) Removing partial-key dependencies to get to 2NF might leave all the relations in 5NF.

Answer (score 1):

）We can use the Armstrong Axioms to get the F+

> A -> D,E,F,G
>
> B -> C (A,B -> D is ignored because A -> D)
>
> E,F -> G

We can get the primary key(A,B).

According to the definition of BCNF, we have to separate A-> (E,F), B->C,  A -> D and (E,F) -> G from the original schema.

> (A,B)   Primary key(A,B)
>
> (B,C)         Primary Key(B)
>
> (A,D)         Primary Key(A)
>
> (A,E,F)  Primary Key(A)
>
> (E,F,G)       Primary Key(E,F)

That's BCNF decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Table 1: A, B, D, E, F with composite primary keys (A, B) and foreign key( B) refer to table 2(B)
Table 2: B, C with B is primary key
Table 3: A, E, F, G with composite primary keys(A, E, F)